# How the scala programing language run internally?

Tags: scala

**How** the **Scala** Programming Language run internally ?
**Advantage** of using Scala over Java?

Comment: @MitchWheat Blasphemy!

Comment: No no no!  Not the fruit wars again!

Comment: As a new comer in scala would like to get more about the scala Programming language , I was searching for architectural design of Scala Language .. if you know plz answer me or suggest the best book which I can go through .. please don't hesitate to answer

Comment: @JobyThomas StackOverflow is a Q&A forum, not a forum for general discussions. A good starting point for answering your question would be to read the Wikipedia article on Scala, and afterwards the documentation on scala-lang.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala is compiled to Java bytecode, executed by the same JVM that runs Java programs, using the same JDK class library plus a small extra Scala runtime library.

The advantages are mostly for the programmer.

Comment: Does Scala runtime library built on python ?

Comment: No. It builds on the JDK class library.

Comment: Is this the combination of different Platforms JVM and  LLVM(Low Level Virtual Machine) ?

Comment: "Hotspot Compiler" is the JIT product in OpenJDK. LLVM is a separate toolkit aimed at doing similar things, but not used in your average JDK (OpenJDK, Oracle, etc).

Comment: So only for compiling we needed Scala, once it's compiled it will convert to ByteCode, and that will be platform independent so that we can run the bytecode in any machine which is having JRE - Correct me if I am Wrong

Comment: Yes. Any JRE (or maybe JDK is required) can run it. You do need the Scala runtime library, too (scala.jar), just like any other Java program can depend on some jar files.

Comment: In which case we can suggest for SCALA language , as an architect  ?